# Retrieving a user's conversations together with last sent and received timestamps

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to retrieve a list of all users that a particular user has exchanged
messages with, along with the timestamp of the last message sent and the
timestamp of the last message received. I want to do this in a single query.

The result would be something like this:

```
[
    [0] {
                :uname => "fred",
        :last_received => 2013-04-09 22:47:20 UTC,
            :last_sent => 2013-04-09 22:47:28 UTC
    },
    [1] {
                :uname => "barney",
        :last_received => nil,
            :last_sent => 2013-06-16 16:25:56 UTC
    },
    [2] {
                :uname => "dino",
        :last_received => 2013-06-09 17:52:54 UTC,
            :last_sent => 2013-06-10 15:56:52 UTC
    }
]
```

The simplified schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id serial NOT NULL,
  uname text NOT NULL,
  created_at timestamp without time zone DEFAULT timezone('utc'::text, now())
)

CREATE TABLE messages (
  id serial NOT NULL,
  sender_id integer NOT NULL,
  recipient_id integer NOT NULL,
  message_text_id integer,
  created_at timestamp without time zone DEFAULT timezone('utc'::text, now())
)
```

I have a query that does this, but since it does left joins on Users, I'm
concerned that it will become slow as the number of Users increases -- I
don't know whether postgresql will optimize it to avoid this happening.

```
WITH t AS (
    select sender_id, recipient_id, max(created_at) as latest_date
    from messages
    where sender_id = #{id} or recipient_id = #{id}
    group by sender_id, recipient_id
)
select uname, t1.latest_date last_received, t2.latest_date last_sent
from users
left join t t1 on t1.sender_id    = users.id and t1.sender_id != #{id}
left join t t2 on t2.recipient_id = users.id and t2.recipient_id != #{id}
where t1.latest_date is not null or t2.latest_date is not null
```

I would be interested to learn whether postgresql will optimize this, and also to see better ways of performing the same query.

Thanks.
Marc

Comment: There are a lot of datamodelling issues with this structure. 0) `users.id` should be a PK 1) `{sender_id,recipient_id}` are probably FK to `users(id)` 2) simalar for `{message_text_id}` which probably points (1->1 ?) to a separate message_test table. 3) {messages.id} is a surrogate key and might not be needed at all. 4) `{users.uname}` _could_ have an unique constraint. 5) `{sender_id, created_at}` _could_ be a candidate key for messages. 6) `{recipient_id, created_at}` )might be a CK. 7 `{message_ext_id}` _could_ be a CK, too. 7) `{created_at}` might need a NOT NULL constraint.

Comment: I didn't include the constraints; as I mentioned, this is simplified schema.

The constraints you mention are all present. In addition, {message_text_id} is also an FK, but many to one, so as to support sending messages to multiple users (e.g. newsletters).

{messages.id} is not necessarily needed, but we have a design rule which mandates an id (or uuid) PK on every table. {created_at} is also on all tables, along with {updated_at}. Both have not null constraints.

Having {sender_id, created_at} as a good idea, and makes a lot of sense.

Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: The problem is that query optimisation cannot be done on a simplfied schema,  the key-structure will dominate the queryplan generation / selection. (given distribution of data + tuning constants)

Comment: On a more serious note: you should really provide **sample data** for a question like this!

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: no, at the NSA they don't have designrules that dictate a surrogate key.(they would use _hubs_ instead) Sounds more like MI4 to me ;-)

Comment: @wildplasser: And how would *you* know about *internal* rules of the NSA, huh? ;)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: well, how could _you_ falsify my statements? (maybe Goedel's conjuncture doesn't apply here ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try something along the following lines - try using `explain` on to see which looks the best.

```
SELECT u.uname, max(x.last_received) last_received, max(x.last_sent) last_sent
FROM (
    SELECT sender_id user_id, max(created_at) last_received, null last_sent
    FROM messages
    WHERE recipient_id = #{id}
    GROUP BY recipient_id 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT recipient_id user_id, null last_received,  max(created_at) last_sent
    FROM messages
    WHERE sender_id = #{id}
    GROUP BY sender_id
) x 
JOIN users u 
ON x.user_id = u.user_id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I added a few tweaks to fix some syntax errors. This looks a lot better than the original. And the Users join is in a much better place, imo.

Comment: I'd suggest pushing the `join users` into the CTE directly, to get two separate joins that are union'ed as needed. This will yield a better query plan.